# Life-threatening situations

Tags: practical-islam, muslim-practices, medical, sick

I wonder what Islam, more specifically the Quran or one of the many hadeeth have to say when it comes to life-threatening diseases. Many muslim people think they have to suffer the illness they're battling right now whereas they are good treatments that help save their lives.

> My question now is: Is that one obligated to use that treatment to save their own life or does that person needs to suffer from that illness and potentially die? Isn't that considered suicide?

L.S.:

Please give me supporting evidence with source references.
Thank you

Comment: I think all evidences could be interpreted in either way. So the problem is not within Islam but within the interpretation. I don't know about a hadith that tells us to look for a treatment where any "spiritual" or "faith"-related part could be excluded, but Allah knows best.

Comment: Could you provide hadith that support the fact to undergo that treatment? And maybe to deny it too?